# Graphic issue presenting MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I've this strange issue when i'm presenting a MFMessageComposeViewController in my app!

I don't know what this black bar is and i'm unable to remove the app logo from the NavigationBar.

[image: The MessageCompose view controller draws over my nav bar]

And here is the code for presenting the controller

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
[[messageController navigationBar] setBarTintColor:SMAN_ORANGE_COLOR];
[[messageController navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[messageController setRecipients:recipents];
[messageController setBody:message];

// Present message view controller on screen
[self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue subclassing my UINavigationController and changing the appearance of it with `[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[myNavControllerSubclass class], nil]`

Answer (score 1):

To remove the app logo, try to add in your method above the following code:

```
messageController.navigationItem.titleView = [UIImageView new];
```

To change the Status Bar style (White Color) add the following code before presenting the **messageController**:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

Also in your **.plist** file set:

**View controller-based status bar appearance** to **NO**

Comment: @AlessandroLucarini can you tell me how and where did you set the app logo in the navigationBar?

Answer (score 0):

```
   [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO];
}];
```

this works in ios 8 for the white status bar

Refer answer #1 also.

Answer (score -1):

As per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html) you can only present it modally.

```
[self presentModalViewController:messageController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I think this method is deprecated.

Comment: It is. Nevertheless, it is still what Apple recommends according to the docs.